# Which was the first Indian mythological movie to use the phrase 'Narayana, Narayana' whenever Sage Narada appears on the scene?

Tags: cinema-history, indian-cinema

Viewers of mythological movies made in many prominent Indian languages (such as Tamil, Telugu, Kannada and Hindi), for many decades now, will instantly recognize the phrase 'Narayana Narayana', as the one that Sage Narada uses whenever he enters any scene, particularly ones where he enters the Abode of Lord Vishnu. This is true even to this day and has almost become the norm, even for socio-mythological movies where Sage Narada is a role.

Which movie started this practice?